# Having an issue getting ANYTHING to apply styles within nested DIVs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've already asked Google about this, and I've spent quite a long time experimenting. I can't possibly recreate the entire HTML and CSS environment this is occurring in, but this is part of it:

```css
#footer-copyright{
    clear:both;
    color:black !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer" class="fullwidth">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="footer-section-one" class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Section One')) : endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-section-two" class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
            <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Section Two')) : endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p id="footer-copyright">This text is immune to formatting</p>
    </div>
    </footer>
```

No matter what I've tried, the text "This text is immune to formatting" is displayed in the p style for the footer object. I've tried making the CSS ID more specific (footer.footer-copyright). I've tried putting the ID on the DIV, and then specifying the style is for "#footer-copyright p{". I've tried footer-copyright as a class style and as a style for that particular ID (as it is now). I don't want to bore you listing all the things I've tried, but think permutations and combinations.

I've spent quite a bit of time in Chrome inspecting the paragraph, and it mostly seems to have no style at all, or to take the style defined by #footer p.

The only thing that I've found works is to completely override the CSS and put the style info into the paragraph itself ("

If you can, please explain why I can't seem to override the parent object's CSS style, and how to use Chrome's reporting of the HTML hierarchy to understand how to specify the CSS style.

THANKS!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5z8xznj7/ seems to work fine.

Comment: You need to provide an example the demonstrates the problem. I applaud your attempt at brevity here but it does not show the actual problem. Try and expand your example to actually show the problem. Doing this one step at a time on your end may actually show you where the problem lies. Without more info we are guessing.

Comment: OK, perhaps in an isolated environment, the CSS works as designed. In the actual site, it just f'ing doesn't, and that's what I'm trying to understand. The site's in Beta (not released), so I have uploaded the "ideal" footer.php, just as in the pseudo-code above, but in this site, the text is WHITE and the wrong size, and ... Here's the URL to the site: http://dothemostgood.staging.wpengine.com.

Comment: On the real site, the only rule that matches that element is `#footer p { color: #fff }`. The HTML tag doesn't have the id `footer-copyright`. it's just a plain `<p>` tag and the rule doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

It does work in the snippet which uses your code (see below)

If you need a more specific selector, you can use this one:

```
footer#footer > div.container > p#footer-copyright { ... }
```

This takes into account all tags, classes and IDs you included in your code.

(I added a background color to the rule to verify it)

```css
footer#footer > div.container > p#footer-copyright {
  clear: both;
  color: black !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  background: #fa0;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer" class="fullwidth">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="footer-section-one" class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
      <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Section One')) : endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-section-two" class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
      <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer Section Two')) : endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="footer-copyright">This text is actually NOT immune to formatting</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I might give that a try. Can you explain how this relates to what I see in Chrome? The Chrome CSS hierarchy shows html body footer#footer.fullwidth div.container p.

Comment: That's even more specific, using every element, class and ID that's there for this particular filepath. `html body` are simply the parent elements of `footer`, `footer#footer.fullwidth` adds the class which is assigned to `footer` in addition to the ID which is already assigned to it. The one thing it *doesn't`add (I don't know why) is the ID of `p`, i.e. `footer-copyright` which I added in the selector. Anyway, both selectors are extremely specific. If there isn't any other selector which deliberately  tries to be even more specific, both should work.

Comment: Interestingly (if this weren't driving me crazy, that is), this works on Edge on Windows 10, and does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample above you have this....

```
<div class="container">
  <p id="footer-copyright">This text is actually NOT immune to formatting</p>
</div>
```

In your ACTUAL page you have this...

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Copyright © 2017 - Do The Most Good, Montgomery County, MD</p>
</div>
```

The element (the P tag) in the ACTUAL page is being rendered/styled using these statements...

```
#footer p
{
  color:#fff;
}
```

When, what you want is for it to be styled with this style...

```
#footer-copyright p
{
  clear:both;
  color:black !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
 text-align:center !important;
}
```

So all you need is for your code to be thus....

```
<div class="container">
  <p id="footer-copyright">Copyright © 2017 - Do The Most Good, Montgomery County, MD</p>
</div>
```

It is simply a case of, that the footer-copyright element (the P tag) was not assigned the style because the ID tag was not set.

Comment: Please see the actual website at http://dothemostgood.staging.wpengine.com. There you will see that it does not work. The text is white, and large, rather then black and small. Why is that? If I attach a specific ID to that paragraph, or DIV, or a SPAN, and then set a style for that ID, why is it ignored? I would REALLY like to know. BTW, since you're not in my head I should tell you that the text is the copyright message at the very bottom of every page.  Oh, and I did try setting the paragraph class (instead of the ID) and defining the style using a period. That does not work either!

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the HTML on the page you sent, versus the code you posted.

The declaration dictating the style is:

```
#footer p{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Actually, the following code is not running at all:

```
#footer-copyright p{
    clear:both;
    color:black !important;
    font-size:12px !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}
```

You can see that there is no `#footer-copyright` in your code.

You can run the following in your console:

```
$('#footer-copyright p').length;
$('#footer p').length;
```

`#footer-copyright` returns a length of zero.

Comment: Thanks! That should be helpful.